# Cookie variable undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, undefined

I'm using the following function to list all cookies than check is cookie name equals to what I need. My problem is that cookie value is in gibberish, so i need to retrieve the value again with `$.cookie();` but now I have another problem. the cookie is undefined, even thought the cookie exist and if i put the name i get from `alert(cookieArray[0])` to `$.cookie("cookie_name");` instead of `$.cookie(cookieArray[0]);` it does work.

```
function listCookies() {
    var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var aString = '';
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
        if(theCookies[i].indexOf("my_cookie-") >= 0){
                cookieArray = theCookies[i].split("=");
                theCookie = cookieArray[0];
                cookieInfo = $.cookie(theCookie);
                alert(cookieInfo);
           }
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you just need to trim it: `cookieInfo = $.cookie($.trim(theCookie));`  What is the exact value of string `theCookie`?

Comment: yep, trim did it. thanks!